# How to manually segue PFFile from PFQueryTableViewController to another ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a PFQueryTableViewController and I want to manually segue an image from my PFTableViewCell to my DetailsViewController. The name and messages(the two labels) are displayed when I run the app but not the image from Parse. How do I manually segue PFFiles from a PFQueryTableViewController and access the properties in the viewDidLoad of my DetailsViewController?

```
   var nameToPass = String()
  var messageToPass = String()
  var photoToPass = PFFile()

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   let object = objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
   self.nameToPass = object!.objectForKey("account") as! String
   self.messageToPass = object!.objectForKey("message") as! String
   self.photoToPass = object!.objectForKey("profileImg") as! PFFile
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("manualSegue", sender: self)


}

 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)  {
if segue.identifier == "PostDetail" {
     let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailsViewController
    destination.username = self.nameToPass
    destination.usermessage = self.messageToPass
    destination.userphoto = self.photoToPass
   }
```

Here is my DetailsViewController:

```
 var username: String?
var usermessage: String?
var userphoto:PFFile?

@IBOutlet weak var PostName: UILabel?
@IBOutlet weak var PostMessage: UILabel?
@IBOutlet weak var PostPhoto:PFImageView
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    PostName?.text = username ?? "nil"
    PostMessage?.text = usermessage ?? "nil"
    PostPhoto?.image = userphoto ?? "nil" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your details view controller, you are setting the image property of PostPhoto to the PFFile. You should be setting the file property.

You can also do some error checking to make sure the image was actually passed.

```
if userphoto != nil {
    PostPhoto.file = userphoto
} else {
    print("User photo not passed")
}
```